What is the proper interpretation of the output 'HF' energy of a ground-state Gaussian 16 calculation using the opt keyword (B3LYP)?
I am running calculations to find optimized ground states with Gaussian 16 such as
#opt=(MaxCyc=100) b3lyp/3-21g Pop=reg

for which I get the following output (sparing many of the atomic coord's, it is quite a large molecule):
......
 \H,3.7535203312,1.8056193769,-1.692020166
 \H,3.1390625503,2.454611487,98.8798116905\H,-3.992271883,0.7445899437,
 98.4308237185\\Version=ES64L-G16RevB.01\State=1-A\ **HF=-33820.3717253** \RM
 SD=2.715e-09\RMSF=4.235e-06\Dipole=0.0314366,0.0000096,-0.000002\Quadr

    upole=-627.1379445,-629.2257955,1256.36374,0.0000004,-0.0000951,-17.58
     10182\PG=C01 [X(C892H22)]\\@
    
    
     TIME IS NATURE'S WAY OF MAKING SURE EVERYTHING
     DOESN'T HAPPEN AT ONCE.
                         - WOODY ALLEN
     Job cpu time:      12 days 21 hours 14 minutes 52.8 seconds.
     Elapsed time:       0 days 13 hours 52 minutes 24.6 seconds.
     File lengths (MBytes):  RWF=  40591 Int=      0 D2E=      0 Chk=   5722 Scr=      1
     Normal termination of Gaussian 16 at Thu Aug 31 02:30:30 2023.

My question regards the proper interpretation of the output value for HF=-33820.3717253, highlighted in bold. I know this is the same value as given at the end of the final optimization cycles when it converges:
SCF Done:  E(RB3LYP) =  -33820.3717253     A.U. after    6 cycles

What does this energy mean exactly? Is it simply the electronic ground state energy from DFT, i.e.
$$
E = \langle T + V + U\rangle, 
$$
with $T$ the kinetic energy, $V$ the external potential energy due to the electron-nuclear attraction, $U$ the electron-electron interaction, and the brackets indicating expectation value? Or does this value also include nuclear-nuclear repulsion? I am having trouble finding a definite description, so if anyone can provide good links, insights or definitions (preferably in the form of equations) that would be most appreciated!

+1. Welcome to our community!

From the Gaussian 16 FAQ:

The full breakdown of the energy is not part of the normal output, but you can get it with two changes change to your input. First, add ExtraLinks=L608 to the route section for your calculation. Next, add input after the geometry specification to tell Link 608 what kind of calculation you are doing. The information you need is in the online G16 IOPs Reference, under the listing for IOp(3/74).

If you want to breakdown of the SCF or DFT energy into all its component parts, you need to modify your input, adding ExtraLinks=L608 to the route section add input after the geometry specification to tell Link 608 what kind of calculation you are doing. For example:
#P b3lyp/6-31g* ExtraLinks=L608
Gaussian Test Job 135: Fe=O perpendicular to ethene, in triplet state.

0 3
X
Fe X  RXFe
C1 X  RXC  Fe  90.
C2 X  RXC  Fe  90.  C1  180.
O  X  RXO  C1  90.  Fe    0.
H1 C1 RCH  C2 CCH   Fe  Angle1
H2 C1 RCH  C2 CCH   Fe -Angle1
H3 C2 RCH  C1 CCH   Fe  Angle2
H4 C2 RCH  C1 CCH   Fe -Angle2

RXFe  1.7118
RXC   0.7560
RXO   3.1306
RCH   1.1000
Angle1 110.54
Angle2 110.53
CCH   117.81
-5

The value -5, at the end is used in this case because this is a B3LYP calculation, and the IOp(3/74).
The output will be something like:
Symmetry not used in FoFCou.
 ET = 1414.828655 EV = -3843.476430  EJ = 849.492336 EK = -74.206791 ENuc = 238.494946

 A=0 I= 1 IExCor=  402 IRadAn=       4 ScaHFX=  0.200000
          ScaDFX=  0.800000  0.720000  1.000000  0.810000
 HFx=  0.000000  0.000000  1.000000  0.000000  0.000000
 DFx=  0.000000  0.000000  1.000000  0.000000  0.000000
 DFc=  0.000000  0.000000  1.000000  0.000000  0.000000
 ENTVJ = -1340.660494 Ex = -74.112334 Ec = -2.536856 ETotM2e = -2251.9606613255 ETot = -1417.3096838703

Where the components of the energy will be:

ET: Kinetic energy
EV: Electron-Nucleus Attraction
EJ: Coulomb term
EK: Hartree-Fock Exchange using the DFT density
ENuc: Nucleus-Nucleus Repulsion
ScaHFX: Scaling factor for the HF exchange
ScaDFX: Scaling factor for the DFT exchange
ENTVJ:ENuc + ET + EV + EJ
Ex: Exchange term = EK * ScaHFX + DFT-Exchange * ScaDFX
Ec: Correlation term
ETot: Total Energy (SCF Energy) = ET + EV + EJ + Ex + Ec + ENuc


Thank you, this is very valuable information for future calculations and I believe it answers my question. If I am not mistaken, it seems that I can use this to isolate the purely electronic energy by calculating Eelec = ETot - ENuc, where ETot is the 'HF' energy that I initially asked about? Or am I interpreting this incorrectly?
